# Benefits of saturation in activation functions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent, backpropagation

It's known that saturation of [activation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) in neural networks leads to [vanishing gradients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient) or dead units, so modern practice often avoids them, instead opting for e.g. [ReLUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)), Leaky ReLUs and other variants that don't saturate.

Perhaps now in retrospect, it seems obvious that saturation and null gradients are undesirable, but it's surprising that it took so long for non-saturating activation functions to become widespread considering the long history of neural networks, and the fact that differentiation was fundamental to their training.

What was a motivation behind their original use? Was saturation a desirable property at the time perhaps because people used to not "stack layers" as much? (in the last layer one often expects bounded quantities, e.g. softmax for getting probabilities). Or was / is there any other benefit to saturation?

Comment: Just a guess, not an answer -- The Cybenko UAT was probably one reason -- loosely, we can use a finite number of sigmoidal units to approximate specific functions. My guess is that this result inspired lots of researchers to jump to the conclusion that sigmoidal networks were automatically good choice because Cybenko had a nice theorem. But as you explain in your question, just because some network exists that will achieve our desired approximation, this doesn't imply that specific network is easily discovered or trained. So, I wonder if this was a case of slippery reasoning.